# Tex capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size = 5000]

Tags: bibtex, errors, memory

This is the error I am getting since I have added some new references to my .bib file. I think is more than a filled stack. Any ideas? [references.bib](https://www.dropbox.com/s/izcuovs26vwzdmg/references.bib)

It was requested a minimum working example but I am working on a template and it was quite difficult for me cut it out. This is my complete structure. The master document is thesis.tex and the problem is raised only under related_work chapter. If you have the time to look at it, I would highly appreciate it. Here is the complete [document](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/92534/thesis.zip).

Comment: The BIB file looks fine to me. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that generates this problem with this BIB file.

Comment: There is no related_work chapter in your very non-minimal example (which compiles without error).

Comment: @ShinTakezou @Martin it looks like when i am changing `\bibliographystyle{Latex/Classes/PhDbiblio-url2}` to another class like `\bibliographystyle{Latex/Classes/PhDbiblio-case}` the problem is getting resolved.

Comment: even with url2, I can't reproduce the error. It goes fine for me.

Comment: It compiles fine for me, too.  My stack size is set to 5000.  What TeX distribution do you use?

Comment: @Jan Kile 2.0.85

Comment: Hm, as far as I know, kile is an editor, not a TeX distribution.  What system do you use?  With kile, chances are it is some sort of linux.  Most linux distros have an old version of TeXLive, usually 2009, installed on them, but when I tried to compile with TeXLive2009, it still compiled fine.

Comment: @Jan you are right, TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
kpathsea version 5.0.0, it compiles to both my setups with the case style. seems pretty strange, is the include related_work under thesis.text uncommented? Just in case.

Comment: Chris, there is something strange going on.  I downloaded and unzipped the "complete document" you link to from your question, and I cannot find any mention of "related_work" anywhere.  The file `thesis.tex` does not contain the string `related`, and there seems to be no file anywhere in the archive that would have the string `related` in its name.

Comment: @Jan I don't have a clue what happened, I have updated the link with my latest code, which throws the error, thank you for everything, I am delivering tomorrow but only for curiosity i have to know whats wrong, i don't like my stacks flooded :(

Answer (score 93, accepted):

It seems that the `PhDbiblio-url2` bibliography style does not want the `url` field to contain `\url{...}`.  It takes care of the url formating itself, enclosing the contents of the `url` field in `\href{...}`.

If you have something like

```
url = {\url{http://example.com/}};
```

in you `.bib` file, the `PhDbiblio-url2` style translates that into

```
\href{\url{http://example.com/}}
```

which creates an infinite loop in the `hyperref` package.

The proper way to include url in the bibliography, when using this style, is just

```
url = {http://example.com};
```

Comment: I found also url = "\url{http://example.com/}"; making the error too. Just correct it as well using ctrl+F buttons.

Answer (score 49):

Not a useful general answer, but a specific case in **Beamer**:

A `\begin{block}` statement (without a name option) will cause this error. The correct format is `\begin{block}{Block title}`, or `\begin{block}{}` if you want no title.

Comment: This is the right answer

Comment: @Amir: No, it is quite specifically the wrong answer for the question, since the question is not about beamer.

Comment: @naught101 but if you have the beamer problem, google the error, you end up here, so it IS a VERY useful answer (:

Comment: @drevicko: *useful*: yes, *right*: no :)

Answer (score 11):

There's a config file where some numbers about "memory" TeX uses are written, I have it into `/etc/texmf/texmf.cnf`; you may need to change some value and regenerate formats.

```
stack_size = 5000        % simultaneous input sources
```

**Add**

Of course the problem may arise from a bug in TeX macros you're using, that consumes all the stack; so we need more information.

**EDIT**

If you want to edit that file, avoid editing `/etc/texmf/texmf.cnf` as always in configuration files. Instead edit the specific file in `/etc/texmf/texmf.d/` - on Ubuntu currently `/etc/texmf/texmf.d/95NonPath.cnf`.

After editing the file you have to execute `update-texmf` to rewrite the configuration file.

**EDIT2**

Often it happens you can't have access to /etc or other system directories, so you need your own cnf file (and TeX tree). [This link](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-privinst) talks about it.

Comment: Changing the stack size won't fix it. It's **always** some TeX macro.

Comment: The stack_size threw another error on a param_size, it didn't fix it as mentioned.

Comment: @Martin not at all. It will fix it, if it's not a bug but a real need of some complex macro. Once I needed it to do some heavy tricks. If it wouldn't be so, setting another value for stack_size, like 100, wouldn't cause problems.

Comment: @Chris-Top we need investigate better your work; I've seen you put a link, unfortunately it is blocked by job websense, so I'll take a look later (very later)

Comment: ... so later that I've forgot... anyway about the EDIT, the best way should be to set up things so that a common user has no to edit files in /etc at all, since common users usually can't edit them unless there's an admin flaw.

Comment: Remark, you can probably also specify this on command-line using `-cnf-line`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/587178/250119.

Answer (score 11):

I found the solution: there was a conflict between hyperref and frenchle, so I got it fixed by replacing `\usepackage{frenchle}` by `\usepackage[french]{babel}`.

Comment: Please note that this very general error can occur for a wide variety of reasons. While switching from `frenchle` to the standard `babel` package (which is indeed very recommendable) removed the error in your document, it doesn't mean that it is a general solution.

Answer (score 5):

Another answer which only applies to **Beamer**:

Somehow beamer doesn't like the `'` in formulas. That means if I write `$t'$` I get the error, whereas `$t^\prime$` works. I'm not sure if this only happens under certain conditions -- just mentioning it here since it's another possible source of this error.

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct answer is to find an MWE.

In my case, the error message pointed to the \maketitle command, which was of no help.  I found I could eliminate the entire body of the document and still got the error.  I eventually traced the problem to the use of \thanks{} within \author{}, which is supported by article and several other document classes, but not acmart and amsart.  The class documentation says to use \authornote{} instead, and outside \author{}.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it works after I clear the cache in the overleaf.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error was caused by typing `documentclass[article]` instead of `documentclass{article}`