# Bibliography is shown on partially

Tags: bibliographies, errors

In the References list at the end of my latex document, only the first 14 references are shown, while the others are not (I use a bib file with around 50 references).

The error is:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=4000].
\bibsgerman ...ef \Btxeditorlong {\btxeditorlong }
                                              \def \Btxeditorsshort ##1{...
l.153
```

What could trigger this?

Comment: Without seeing the code, I would recommend you download JabRef and inspect the bib file for syntax error.  This can be a result of a missing grouping symbol.

Comment: These kinds of errors are usually caused by some kind of infinite recursions, e.g. like macros calling themselves. If possible, please provide a minimal example that shows the issue. Without further information it's impossible to track it down. Also, have a look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24247/tex-capacity-exceeded-sorry-input-stack-size-5000) and the accepted answer. Maybe you're problem is related to it.

Comment: Seeing that the part of memory which is exausted is the "save size" makes me suspect of a programming error in your macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestions. I fixed the problem by increasing the "save_size" limit in my Latex Editor (Bakoma Tex).

Comment: It's quite probable that you've only cured the symptoms, rather than the disease.