# tex capacity exceeded when including url in .bib file

Tags: bibtex

When I include url in the .bib file latex throws the error:
Tex capacity exceeded, sorry[save size=5000]

Do you have any idea why?
Below I paste the package I use and one reference

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %write accent without the \ [' ` ^] 
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp} % + the above package use euro directly
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{harvard}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}

as in \cite{AhlinTownsend2007}, blah, blah blah...
\cite{DufloBanerjee2013}

\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

and the test.bib file

```
@article {AhlinTownsend2007,
author = {Ahlin, Christian and Townsend, Robert M.},
title = {Using Repayment Data to Test Across Models of Joint Liability Lending*},
journal = {The Economic Journal},
volume = {117},
publisher = {Blackwell Publishing Ltd},
number = {517},
pages = {F11-F51},
issn = {1468-0297},
doi = {10.1111/j.1468-0297.2007.02014.x},
url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1468-0297.2007.02014.x},
year = {2007},
}

@techreport{DufloBanerjee2013,
title={The miracle of microfinance? Evidence from a randomized evaluation},
author={Duflo, Esther and Banerjee, Abhijit and Glennerster, Rachel and Kinnan, Cynthia G},
year={2013},
institution={National Bureau of Economic Research},

}
```

Comment: Could you please complete your code to make a small document demonstrating the issue? That is much more useful than mere code fragments.

Comment: If I create a `.bib` file and add `\cite{AhlinTownsend2007}` plus `\bibliographystyle{agsm}`, I don't get any error. However, in general, `hyperref` should be loaded last, surely after `harvard`.

Comment: @cfr here is the complete code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid I also cannot replicate the capacity-exceedance error you're reporting.

However, I have two suggestions -- both motivated by the fact that you're using the `hyperref` package -- which may be useful. Moreover, one of these suggestions involves using `natbib` instead of `harvard`. With this change, the capacity-exceedance error may also disappear on its own.

- If you want a URL string to be an active hyperlink that users can click on, you should write the url field as

  ```
  url = {\url{http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1468-0297.2007.02014.x}},
  ```

  instead of as

  ```
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1468-0297.2007.02014.x},
  ```
- If you want the citation callouts in the body of the document to become hyperlinks to the corresponding entries in the bibliography, don't load the `harvard` citation management package. Instead, load the `natbib` citation management package and the auxiliary `har2nat` package. Since you're using the `agsm` bibliography style, which is part of the `harvard` package, it's necessary to load `har2nat`, as it provides macros that "translate" some of the `harvard`-specific macros into forms that `natbib` can process. (When switching from `harvard` to `natbib`/`har2nat`, it's generally necessary to delete all auxiliary files that were created during an earlier compilation run.)

In the example below, note that the `natbib` package is loaded with the option `longnamesfirst` in order to replicate the feature of the `harvard` package that the names of all authors should be provided the first time a given entry is cited. (Subsequent callouts to a given entry are typeset as `FirstAuthor et al.`.) Separately, observe that one should encase the word `Evidence` in curly braces in order to keep it from being converted to all-lowercase.

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents} % make this a self-contained example
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib} 
@article {AhlinTownsend2007,
  author = {Ahlin, Christian and Townsend, Robert M.},
  title = {Using Repayment Data to Test Across Models of Joint Liability Lending},
  journal = {The Economic Journal},
  volume = {117},
  publisher = {Blackwell Publishing Ltd},
  number = {517},
  pages = {F11-F51},
  issn = {1468-0297},
  doi = {10.1111/j.1468-0297.2007.02014.x},
  url = {\url{http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1468-0297.2007.02014.x}},
  year = {2007},
}
@techreport{DufloBanerjee2013,
  title={The miracle of microfinance? {Evidence} from a randomized evaluation},
  author={Duflo, Esther and Banerjee, Abhijit and Glennerster, Rachel and Kinnan, Cynthia G},
  year={2013},
  institution={National Bureau of Economic Research},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp} 
\usepackage{babel}
%%%\usepackage{harvard} 
\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib} 
\usepackage{har2nat}                % emulate harvard-type macros for natbib
\bibliographystyle{agsm} % agsm is part of the "harvard" package
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\dots as in \cite{AhlinTownsend2007}, blah, blah blah\dots
\cite{DufloBanerjee2013}

\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll consider this alternative. This post seems to contradict the right way to put url in a bib file. I am having a hard time finding the problem. I generally use Auctex on linux, there is no compilation problem. The problem arise only in Texwork on windows.

Comment: Here is the [post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24247/tex-capacity-exceeded-sorry-input-stack-size-5000).

Comment: @DJJ - I'm not sure what you mean by "the right way" to provide a URL. You certainly don't have to provide the `\url` instruction. However, if `\url` is omitted, the URL string will *not* be typeset as an active hyperlink. Moreover, overfull lines and other bad line break situations may occur if you omit the `\url` "wrapper", because LaTeX probably has no idea how to break a long URL string across lines.

Comment: @djj - which TeX distribution do you use on your windows machine, and how recently was it updated?

Comment: @djj - Thanks for the comment that provides a link to an earlier posting that was also contending with capacity-exceeded problems. However, AFAICT the `PhDbiblio-url2` bibliography style (which was used in the earlier posting) and the `agsm` bibliography style (which is what you use) do not do the same things with the contents of the `url` field. I'd thus say you're safe using the `\url` wrapper macro.

Comment: your solution works fine and the Tex distribution I'm working with on Windows is Miktex 2.9 version: 0.4.3r.857. And thanks for the clarification about the post as well. I was chasing the wrong hare.