# Figure environment exceeds TeX capacity

Tags: capacity

I'm trying to include a figure environment in this [project](https://www.overleaf.com/4366977781gbgfhwrvjnht) (see main.tex file line 76). However, as soon as I include the figure environment, the compiler says that TeX capacity has been exceeded. The same happens in TeXStudio. If I remove the figure environment, the \includegraphics command works perfectly. I have been looking around about this problem, and I think it may be something related with the citation (I have fixed all the [url](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175176/tex-capacity-exceeded-when-including-url-in-bib-file) lines in the .bib file and still doesn't work). Please, if anyone can help me I will be very grateful, because I don't know what's happening. It never happened before.

Comment: The problem lies within the document class (`muthesis_2020.cls`). Comment out lines 265-270.

Comment: Wow, wonderful. Now it works. Could u explain what was happening? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a couple of thing:

(1) From `mysetup.sty` delete the package `setspace` and also the line `\spacing{1.5}`.

(2) Replace `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}` with  `\linespread{1.41}` or with other value you like to expand the lines separation.

The beginning of `mysetup.sty` should now look like

```
%%% DOCUMENT STRUCTURE  

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm} 
 \linespread{1.41} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\setlength{\parskip}{0cm}   
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\textbf{\arabic{enumi}.}}

%%% TYPOGRAPHY,  LANGUAGE,  ENCODING
```

(3) For the figure use

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{img/variance_mu0_5_r0_02_sigma0_3_rho1_6_z2-eps-converted-to.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

To get

[image: a]

**Notes**

I compiled the full work using TeXstudio, pdflatex and lualatex with the same result. Several  `Overfull \hbox` that will need to be corrected. Adding `\usepackage{showframe}` makes it easy to find the culprits in a multifile project.

[image: b]

To avoid conflicts with my windows instalation I changed the name of the subdirectory `aux`  to `xtras`

Delete duplicate packages loaded both in your preamble and in `mysetup.sty`.

Comment: Many thanks, really!