# A problem with .bib entry

Tags: bibtex

For the following bib entry

```
@article {CAIM:CAIM475,
author = {Gassmann, Oliver and Zeschky, Marco},
title = {Opening up the Solution Space: The Role of Analogical Thinking for Breakthrough Product Innovation},
journal = {Creativity and Innovation Management},
volume = {17},
number = {2},
publisher = {Blackwell Publishing Ltd},
issn = {1467-8691},
url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1467-8691.2008.00475.x},
doi = {10.1111/j.1467-8691.2008.00475.x},
pages = {97--106},
year = {2008},
}
```

I get the error

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\hyper@normalise ->\begingroup \catcode `\

                                           \active \def 
{ }\catcode `\%\act...
l.8 ...x.doi.org/10.1111/j.1467-8691.2008.00475.x}
```

That error vanishes if I remove the url entry. I am sure that something is wrong with the syntax. I exported the bibtex citation from the article website:

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-8691.2008.00475.x/full

Any clues on what is wrong with the url line?

Comment: We are going to need a minimal working example showing your LaTeX input here: there's nothing obvious about the `.bib` entry to raise concerns.

Comment: I do not get any errors pertaining to my latex entry per se. As I mentioned, if I were to remove the url field in the bib entry, the PDF output is generated without any errors. Here is a similar link I found in one of the previous discussions which mentions about url related issue: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24247/tex-capacity-exceeded-sorry-input-stack-size-5000 I see a similar error in my case as well.

Comment: While the fact that removing the `url` field removes the issue tells us there is possibly something wrong with your document class or bibstyle in terms of `url` formatting, it's not going to get us to an answer. We need to see an example of your LaTeX input: that is where the issue will be.