# Convince pdflatex et al. to not restrict console output to 78 columns

Tags: pdftex, terminal-output, console

For some reason I'm unaware of, every *latex executable I've used has the strange habit of wrapping its console output at 78 columns. That's a bit surprising, since it always either ends up on a terminal or in a log file, and it's annoying, because more often than not it breaks long file names, that I could otherwise read (or parse) on a single line.

Is there a way to disable that?

Comment: yes, you can change the value in texmf.cnf (assuming texlive).

Comment: you have bought a wide teletype with more than 80 columns to connect to your mainframe?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle crazy, right? It even supports more than 2 different background colors! (correct me, but even for a VT100, the OS would've broken lines as necessary, I think the likeliest explanation is "printing tex errors to line printers", but I *honestly* can't imagine a use case for that – even 40 years ago.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default `texmf.cnf` has

```
% It's probably inadvisable to change these. At any rate, we must have:
% 45 < error_line      < 255;
% 30 < half_error_line < error_line - 15;
% 60 <= max_print_line;
% These apply to TeX, Metafont, and MetaPost.
error_line = 79
half_error_line = 50
max_print_line = 79
```

so you can set these in your local texmf.cnf (or as environment settings) oe on the command line `-cnf-line=max_print_line=254`

Comment: Thanks! This is a "uff, no, but you can at least have 254 instead of 78." This is, mildly put, a bit backwards :) I can see how a piece of software wouldn't want to accumulate arbitrarily large buffers for output, but err, < 256 characters, that can't be that hard for a system running *TeX* of all things!

Comment: Thank you for that perspective!

Comment: The setting can also be extended on the command line: `-cnf-line=max_print_line=254`

Comment: ah, interesting, @HeikoOberdiek!

Comment: For the interested reader:  I'm using `max_print_line=200000` without problem now,